# The bodyParser not work when post "form-data" with POSTMAN

Tags: node.js, express, urlencode, form-data, body-parser

the HTTP preview:

```
POST /kflq_webcfg/v1/update HTTP/1.1
Host: h.innmall.cn
Cache-Control: no-cache

----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data"

{"orderInnerId":"12146","p":{"imei":"866568022978356","mac":"58:1f:28:ea:4d:e1","os":"android4.4.2","platform":"Android","ptype":"H60-L01_19_4.4.2","version":"6.1.1"},"type":1}
----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="mode"

plain
----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
```

But can parser x-www-form-urlencode:

```
POST /kflq_webcfg/v1/update HTTP/1.1
Host: h.innmall.cn
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

data={"orderInnerId":"12146","p":{"imei":"866568022978356","mac":"58:1f:28:ea:4d:e1","os":"android4.4.2","platform":"Android","ptype":"H60-L01_19_4.4.2","version":"6.1.1"},"type":1}&mode=plain
```

How to solve this problem through the body-parser middleware?

I need these two cases to get the same result.

thank you very much!

Comment: Postman can export HTTP Requests in a wide variety of formats - are you certain you are exporting in the best format for your needs?

Comment: @Eilidh I want to compatible with two cases...

Comment: How do you setup bodyparser?

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin `log.info("装载中间件body-parser...");
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));`

Answer (score 1):

Body-parser cannot handle multipart bodies, you should use something like [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#readme) for that. In addition to handling file uploads multer also parses the text fields of a multipart data into req.body. [Body-parser docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) also give a good explanation.